# Why is תורה sometimes written תורת?

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk, pentateuch-chumash

Why is *Torah* sometimes written in the Torah with a "ת" at the end instead of an "ה"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Gesenius writes in his [Hebrew Grammar](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/89._The_Genitive_and_the_Construct_State):

> (b) The original ־ַת‎ is regularly retained as the feminine termination in the construct state sing. of those nouns which in the absolute state end in ־ָה‎, e.g. מַלְכָּה‎ queen, מַלְכַּת שְׁבָא‎ the queen of Sheba. But the feminine endings ־֫ ־ֶת‎, ־֫ ־ַת‎, and also the plural ־וֹת‎, remain unchanged in the construct state.

Comment: cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taw#T.C4.81.CA.BC_marb.C5.AB.E1.B9.ADah

Comment: The switch to a ת doesn't have to be the construct state. Any case suffix should do it too (ex [II Samuel 1:26](http://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.1.26)) though those are pretty rare in ordinary Hebrew.

Comment: good point! I was thinking horses rather than zebras for what the questioner was asking, though.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick, simple Hebrew grammar:

תורה = Torah

אמת = truth

תורה של אמת = Torah of truth (incorrect way)

תור**ת** אמת = Torah of truth